# JQuery Sticky Content not updating

Tags: jquery, sticky

I'm using this script for some sticky content:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/stickycontent.htm

However, when I pass Ajax values to it (it's containing the results of a calculator), it won't display the passed values as soon as it becomes "sticky" and the page scrolls. However, as soon as I scroll back to the original position and it's not "sticky" anymore, the values re-appear.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here - this is probably easier:

http://www.wholesaleelectronics.co.nz/administration/offers/test.asp

If you enter something in the Quantity field, you'll see the box on the right hand side update. But as soon as you scroll down, you'll see the text disappear.